# How do I find the closest number across columns?

Tags: sql, azure-synapse

I have this table:

```
col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | compare
------+-------+-------+--------
 1.1  | 2.1   | 3.1   | 2
------+-------+-------+--------
 10   | 9     | 1     | 15
```

I want to derive a new column choice indicating the column closest to the compare value:

```
col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | compare | choice
------+-------+-------+---------+-------
 1.1  | 2.1   | 3.1   | 2       | col_2
------+-------+-------+---------+-------
 10   | 9     | 1     | 15      | col_1
```

Choice refers to the column where cell value is closest to the compare value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest method is `apply`:

```
select t.*, v.which as choice
from t cross apply
     (select top (1) v.*
      from (values ('col_1', col_1), ('col_2', col_2), ('col_3', col_3)
           ) v(which, val)
      order by abs(v.val - t.compare)
     ) v;
```

In the event of ties, this returns an arbitrary closest column.

You can also use `case` expressions, but that gets complicated.  With no `NULL` values:

```
select t.*,
       (case when abs(compare - col_1) <= abs(compare - col_3) and
                  abs(compare - col_1) <= abs(compare - col_3)
             then 'col_1'
             when abs(compare - col_2) <= abs(compare - col_3)
             then 'col_2'
             else 'col_3'
         end) as choice
from t;
```

In the event of ties, this returns the first column.